# Can I host Google Analytics or Google Tag Manager scripts locally?

Tags: html, wordpress, web, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I would like to know if there is a way to implement google tag manager into my website without it giving me an error on Gtmetrix under Add expire header

(As seen below)

[image: Add expire header google analytics]

I was thinking if there is a way that you can insert the code in a file and somehow host it on the server itself.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Faz

Comment: From the "wordpress" tag I assumed you use WordPress, but your question doesn't state this. Can you confirm?

Comment: I do use WordPress, just wanted to specify with the tags that I am using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scripts you've highlighted are Google Analytics, not Google Tag Manager, but yeah, you could download them and host them yourself. [Google advises against hosting GTM locally](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032389?hl=en), because you won't automatically receive updates, but you could. There even is a WordPress plugin that helps you in hosting GA locally: [Complete Analytics Optimization Suite (CAOS)](https://dev.daanvandenbergh.com/wordpress-plugins/optimize-analytics-wordpress/)

PS I'm in no way affiliated with the CAOS plugin, just found it on Google. Always test first and use at your own risk.

Comment: Awesome man! thanks, I've tried searching for a solution on the internet but couldn't find one and now that I got this site I can finally get my score 100/100. It's so silly that Google says you should implement it and it blocks you from getting 100/100 score. I'll try it out and post an update if it works.

Comment: Caos works! and they also have a plugin for hosting your fonts locally!

https://wordpress.org/plugins/host-webfonts-local/

Comment: Hi! I'm the developer of CAOS! And I just want to say thank you for mentioning my plugins :D

Comment: Hey @DaanvandenBergh, thanks for the amazing work on those plugins, I use them almost daily, you are a life saviour!